# Hadoop File Empty after Write

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

We have an application that retrieves data from MongoDB and writes to Hadoop cluster.
The data is a list of strings that are converted to JSON and written to Hadoop using the following logic
˚

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", HadoopConstants.HDFS_HOST + HadoopConstants.HDFS_DEFAULT_FS);

FSDataOutputStream out = null;
FileSystem fileSystem = null;
//Create Hadoop FS Path and Directory Structure
if (!fileSystem.exists(new Path(dir))) {
    // Create new Directory
    fileSystem.mkdirs(new Path(dir), FsPermission.getDefault());
    out = fileSystem.create(new Path(filepath));
} else if (fileSystem.exists(new Path(dir))) {
    if (!fileSystem.exists(new Path(filepath))) {
        out = fileSystem.create(new Path(filepath));
    } else if (fileSystem.exists(new Path(filepath))) {
        //should not reach here .
        fileSystem.delete(new Path(filepath), true);
        out = fileSystem.create(new Path(filepath));
    }

}

for (Iterator < String > it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String node = it.next();
    out.writeBytes(node.toString());
    out.writeBytes("\n");
}
LOGGER.debug("Write to HDFS successful");
out.close();
```

The application works well for QA and Staging environments .

In production environment , which has an additional firewall in order to connect to it (This firewall has been opened now in order to grant access for write) , following error is seen .

The file is being created but the final Hadoop file is empty . ie. The size is 0 bytes.

The Hadoop fs –du and Hadoop fsck commands on the file being written is attached in the screenshot. The size after replication during write increases to 384M but then becomes 0 again .

- Is this because out.close() in above code is not being called ?
  This doesn’t explain QA data being written correctly.
- Could it be a firewall issue ?
  The file is being created correctly . Hence doesn’t seem to be connectivity issue . Unless after file is created and opened data is being written and not flushed correctly so as it is saved.

  Following is file specifications during write

$ hadoop fs -du -h file.json
0 384M ...

The size after replication param above increases to 384M and changes to 0 after a while. Does this mean data is arriving but not being flushed correctly to disk?

$ hadoop fsck

- What are some ways I could verify if data is being fetched and arriving from the Hadoop side?

**** UPDATE ****

- Following exception is thrown in client logs during execution of following line:

  out.close();

  HDFSWriter ::Write Failed :: Could not get block locations. Source file "part-m-2017102304-0000.json" - Aborting...
- Hadoop httpfs.out Logs has the following :

  hadoop-httpfs ... INFO httpfsaudit: [/part-m-2017102304-0000.json] offset [0] len [204800]

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have firewall access to the namenode (which can create the file), but not to the datanodes (which are needed to write data to the files).

Get the firewall rules updated so that you also have access to the datanodes.

Comment: You sir , are a genius . Questions : are you saying until out.close() is called no data is physically written to the data nodes ? also should i out.flush() and out.close() after every iteration of list in the for loop or once outside

Comment: Two things: 1. I had the same situation and this fixed it. 2. Data gets written when you have a full block or when you flush or close. Since full blocks are typically 64 or 128Mb, if your file is smaller than that, then it typically gets written only when you call `close()`.

Comment: Thanks . I will test opening firewall for every data node and get back here .Is it enough to open rules for all nodes in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: I opened the firewall to all data nodes . Still get the same exception. I think there is a problem with the ports . Which ports does the data node use to write data .  Does the client need to open those ports ?